# Reminding someone of his salary when doing a bad job

Tags: professionalism

I have multiple questions. Pardon me if I can't construct my questions properly, but here they are:

1. What's the English term for when someone, your boss or your lead, reminds you that you are getting paid properly, so you must do a better job? `Gaslighting` isn't certainly the term.
2. Is this reportable to HR? I assume yes.

2-3 years ago, I got a remote job that I thought I would be happy to have.

Here's the exact chat my lead sent me:

> sry but this is not acceptable. you are very well compensated for this job. I shouldn't be declining every single PR because you don't check things. You rushing and not checking things is eventually ending up in more dev time - biting you in the @$$ at the end

Back then, my rate was okay - same rate with most of the startups in the city.

I'm grateful for that job cause if they didn't hire me, I'd not be where I am now. It took me around 3-4 months before I realized that I should really leave. My salary has increased to **222%** ever since I left that company.

Also, a last question, I guess this is one of the reasons why I posted this. Is it okay to send a message to that guy on LinkedIn to perhaps just say thanks for saying that to me? Or is it immature and it's not a big deal anyway to you?

Ps. I would say that I probably messed up a little bit back then, but once I moved to a new company after that job most of my clients/projects are very grateful to my performance - though I always consider myself as just good enough but definitely not better than most Software Engineers out there.

Comment: I would say it's unprofessional for him to say that but it will open a can of worms if you send it to HR and I certainly wouldn't contact him on LinkedIn. You don't mention whether him "declining every single PR" is justified, so I would focus on that. Is rushing and not checking things causing you to to end in more dev time?

Comment: Thanks both. Silly me, that's the term I was looking for: "unprofessional". I would say I don't have any issue with "constructive criticism". Was that a constructive one? It's an honest question btw. Not reaching out to him makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Wait ... is it your current boss who told you that or your former? I can't really follow the timeline in your question.

Comment: @orithena, I think that the OP's former boss told him that. After that the OP got a job at a new company and his new salary is increased to 222%.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 So ... the question is basically "should I rub my gains into the face of my old boss who mocked me two years ago"??

Comment: @Glenn  What outcome are you trying to achieve by your actions?  Do you imagine you will be successful?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would write it off to experience as rude but constructive criticism.

There is no point taking this further that I can see. You admit to have messed up at that job, so while it could have been less blunt, it was justified.

Answer (score 17):

> What's the English term for when someone, your boss or your lead, reminds you that you are getting paid properly, so you must do a better job?

I'd just call it feedback. It means that your current performance doesn't meet expectations for your level which set by job descriptions, job grade and certainly also by your compensation.

> Is this reportable to HR? I assume yes.

Why??? It's just feedback. It may not be the most politically correct way to say it but it's certainly not an offense in any way, form or shape.

> Is it okay to send a message to that guy on LinkedIn to perhaps just say thanks for saying that to me?

For what purpose? Are you trying to be sarcastic or are you generally grateful? In any case: don't send the message. It's water under the bridge. No one cares and neither should you.

Comment: I would say both, sarcastic but honestly grateful. I won't do it. I appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 7):

> What's the English term for when someone, your boss or your lead, reminds you that you are getting paid properly, so you must do a better job?

"Direct feedback" or perhaps "a warning you need to improve. Fast."

Your lead is telling you that your professional performance is not up to the standard your employer expects from someone at your level (aka your salary). It could perhaps have been phrased better, but (unless part of a bigger picture) is not particularly terrible - in particular, it lets you know what you're doing wrong (submitting bad PRs) and what you need to do to improve (check things more). That is good, actionable feedback you should take on boad.

> Is this reportable to HR? I assume yes.

If this is one incident, absolutely not in no way ever. You will come across as an incredibly thin-skinned individual who is trying to avoid any criticism of your professional failings.

> Is it okay to send a message to that guy on LinkedIn to perhaps just say thanks for saying that to me? Or is it immature

Yes, that would be incredibly immature.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the obvious and good answers here, I want to emphasize something:

#### Never complain to HR about how your boss treats you unless you are ready to make a career-ending stance about it.

HR works for management.  HR does not work for the employees.  Their job is to protect the company, and at this point the person they most likely need to protect the company from is you. The first person HR will call about something that isn't an obvious legal issue, like sexual harassment, is your boss.

Comment: This is bad advice. It leads to a whole load of people all "not complaining" about their terrible boss, because they don't want to be the one fired, while if the company actually knew what was going on the boss would be fired. It explains why so much sexual harassment went on without anybody being called out on it. Bullies love this attitude - it's the one they try to instill in all the people they bully, because it makes them safe from repercussions.

Comment: @DJClayworth, NO.  People have this idea that HR is there to help the employee, I tell you they are not.

Comment: I never said anything like that. Please don't fall into the simplistic trap of  assuming HR are always your enemy.